# Incompatible version constraints on barback:

Tags: dart

Dart Editor version 1.10.0.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.10.0

pubspec.yaml

```
name: project
description: A sample Polymer application
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: any
  observe: any
  bwu_datagrid: any
transformers:
- polymer:
   entry_points: web/project.html
```

Run pub get

```
--- 19:11:03 Running pub get on C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\Dart\project ... ---
Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...
Incompatible version constraints on barback:
- observe 0.9.1+1 depends on version >=0.9.0 <0.11.0
- pub itself depends on version >=0.13.0 <0.15.3

** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **
```

I can't understand what connection is between `observe` which i use in my project and `pub` itself.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why do you think there is a connection between `observe` and `pub` itself? I copied your `pubspec.yaml` and run `pub upgrade` successfully. It's usually better to add concrete version constraints instead of `any`

Comment: After `pub upgrade` it works. Thank you!

Comment: Weird, but glad it works now.